# Generalization of words flats, commercial spaces, garages

Tags: generic-term

There is a house. It has several flats, garages, commercial spaces and some rooms.
Flats, spaces and rooms may be rented or they may be used by the owner of the house.

Is there any general term that would express flats and other things that may be rented?
Is an asset a good word for it?

Comment: In the US people say "units" or "rental units."

Comment: An answer already gives "property", but the key word in the question is *rental* - hence ***rental property***.

Answer (score 1):

The term **property** is used to denote one, or a set of buildings.

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/property) has

> a building or area of land, or both together:
>
> *He owns a number of properties on the south coast.*
>   *The notice said "Private property - keep off!"*
>   *Yes, I've bought my own house - I'm now a man/woman of property!*

The [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/property) has

> **1.1** A building or buildings and the land belonging to it or them.
>
> *he's expanding now, buying property*

Comment: Is the term property also applicable for flats and other parts of building? For example: Can I say that the building consists of the following properties: flat no 1, flat no 2, flat no 3, garage?

Comment: More the other way round: "The property consists of several flats and other buildings."

Comment: Thank you. Is there any general term that would express "a part of the property"? A unit that may be rented such flat, room, etc..?

Comment: "Dwellings", for things that are lived in. For other types of rentable property, you've already used the word that is used in the property business: **unit**. Storage units or Retail units.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that "building" is maybe a better term for what you're describing (rather than "house"). A house implies that it is a living space, so your "commercial space" example wouldn't fit with the term "house."

However, an apartment building could have rooms (studios), flats (individual apartments), or other spaces for rent. Or, an office building would have office spaces for rent, though likely not individual rooms.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I will use "building". Thank you.

Comment: The term "space" might be the term I'm looking for.
May I say this?
"The building has the following spaces for rent: 3 flats, 2 garages, 1 commercial space"

Comment: @Rob I think the term "space" would work very well

Comment: @Rob If you are talking about in Britain, I think I would say "The building comprises the following rental units: 3 flats, 2 garages, and one commercial space".